ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED when http header size is too large
When calling my nuxt app with too many url params (worst case: URL is +/-8kb), I am getting no response. Instead, the ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error appears. The main suspect is Nginx, but I could not find any documentation about this behaviour. Also, there are no traces in the access or error logs.
The next best setting I found is large_client_header_buffers - but I am not getting any 414 error, so I am not sure if this is relevant at all.
Any ideas? 
